# BLE SensorTagEX example runs once on iOS 6.1 Simulator then hangs on subsequent attempts

Tags: core-bluetooth

My environment:

- Mid 2012 MacBook Air
- Mac OS X 10.8.4
- Xcode 4.6.3
- Cirago BTA8000
- ...and TI CC2541 SensorTag (with fresh CR2032 battery)

I have downloaded and installed the SensorTag iOS source code examples and I am attempting to build and run the SensorTagEX example app.

Starting from a fresh Mac restart, I launched Xcode, opened the SensorTagEX project and successfully built and ran the app in the iOS 6.1 Simulator by clicking on Xcode's Run button.  Then I stopped the app in Xcode and quit the simulator to read the source code files.  Then I clicked Xcode's Run button once again but got different results.

The app appears to hang after detecting the SensorTag device.  In the Xcode console, I see:

```
2013-07-23 14:44:07.455 SensorTagEX[1776:c07] Found a BLE Device :        
<CBConcretePeripheral: 0x9553db0 UUID = <CFUUID 0x955f830> 924D7A39- 
DEC2-    2C4B-3E0E-AD485CCFD45C, Name = "TI BLE Sensor Tag", 
IsConnected = NO>


2013-07-23 14:44:07.457 SensorTagEX[1776:c07] Found a BLE Device :     
<CBConcretePeripheral: 0x9553db0 UUID = <CFUUID 0x955f830> 924D7A39-
DEC2-2C4B-3E0E-AD485CCFD45C, Name = "TI BLE Sensor Tag", IsConnected = 
NO>
```

and then nothing else.

If I reboot the Mac and relaunch Xcode, as before, I can run the SensorTagEX app once successfully, then subsequent runs appear to hang, as before.

The SensorTag board has a sticker that says `"1.3 1252"`

Any help or guidance will be much appreciated.

Thanks!